# Uploaded website in DigitalOcean only works if it's under /var/www/html

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I am new to DO and trying to upload my website to my Droplet.

I uploaded my website to root/srv/www/mywebsite/ and modified a file called: **etc/nginx//sites-available/default** to use the folder I just created

So I removed

> root /var/www/html;

Added

> root /srv/www/mywebsite;

then I restart my nginx server, by using the following commands:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

But none of them worked.

Only when I changed back to use the **/var/www/html** path inside default file, then the server starts to work.

Comment: what's output error ?

Comment: Is `/srv/www/mywebsite` accessible by the nginx web server? what are the permissions?

Comment: hi @Oliver how to see that? I am new to Linux.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan if you were asking for the nginx error in its log, there is no error. From the website browsing, it show 404 not found.

Comment: 404 error means nginx error, đid you check nginx error or configure already nginx logs?

Comment: hi @ThanhNguyenVan really thanks for your help, sorry for being a lazy cat, I ended up using the www/html folder to store my website files. Where can I find the nginx errors?

Comment: In /var/log/nginx/